# XSLT which combines two nodes and removes the duplicate values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

**Input:**

```
    <data>

      <root>
        <name>A</name>
        <name>B</name>
      </root>

      <root>
        <name>C</name>
        <name>D</name>
        <name>A</name>
      </root>

    </data>
```

**Output:**

```
<data>
      <root>
        <name>A</name>
        <name>B</name>
        <name>C</name>
        <name>D</name>
      </root>
</data>
```

User enters data in name element of two different nodes. So i want a XSLT which combines two nodes and removes the duplicate values. I tried, but it is not working. Please help me.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you have tried, even if it is not working. Thank you!

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768387/removing-duplicates-in-xml-with-xslt helps you

Comment: Any problem that involves removing duplicates is going to have a very different solution in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. Because both versions are very widely used, you really need to say which you are using. (And the 2.0 solution is going to be much easier, so use 2.0 if you possibly can.)

Comment: @MichaelKay Kay:  I am using XSLT 1.0. Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do grouping queries in XSLT 1.0. Too much like hard work, and since I've been using 2.0 since about 2003, one forgets.

Comment: @kjhughes : It is completely different. Can you suggest some solution for my problem.

Comment: @Michael Kay : What is the solution in XSLT 2.0? I can use this also.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 it's simply

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/data/root/name" group-by=".">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Its not working. Can you suggest some other solution.

Comment: Is that your normal approach to problem solving? If it doesn't work, try something else? If so, you need to rethink your approach. If something doesn't work, you need to find out why, and the first step in that is to examine the symptoms of the failure: when you say "its not working", how exactly does it fail?